# Bootstrap navbar logo/img get smaller when i add a link in it

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I have an image inside the navbar, see example:

http://www.sallydworsky.com/discs.htm

When i add a link to the image, the image gets smaller, see example:

http://www.sallydworsky.com/discs2.htm

I want the image stay the same size when i add the link.  I tried changing the navbar height but that doesn't seem to be the problem. How can I prevent the image from getting smaller when I add a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed your both link through inspect. There is only one problem which cause the site to do that.

```
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 70%}
```

The max-width of .img-fluid of tag a is 70% but in your correct site when you didn't add link (tag a) it was 100%.

There are some way to do it.

1. Add inline-style in your a link tag **Style = {max-width: 100% !important}**
2. Or go to css folder and open bootstrap-4.3.1.css file search for img-fuild and change it's width to 100%. I have attached the snapshot below for help
3. Add in your style css file the following code. (i am not sure for this)

```
.a img-fluid {
max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

[image]

Ping me up if you didn't get it or not found suitable but it will help you 100%.

Comment: You should NOT edit Bootstrap's source code, it you encounter an implementation that doesn't suit your use case, you should create your own custom class

Comment: thanks for the response. i guess i changed the img-fluid to 70% (i forgot) so that the image at 100% would not push the nav toggle button down below it when viewed on a mobile device. now if i change the img-fluid to 100%, i have the problem of the toggle button dropping down underneath the logo.

Comment: That would be good but by changing the Bootstrap code or adding a new (as your use cases) in them wouldn't effect the Bootstrap as much, it's just depends on your requirements of things. Yeah i am agree with you somehow. If the guy thinks that it will not effect anything that's good otherwise more good to go with inline styles or custom classes.

Comment: Then you should use media Queries because it will help you in responsiveness of the site. Example is shown below

@media (min-width: 568px) {
  .a img-fluid {
max-width: 70% !important; // or according to your requirement
}
}

Comment: thanks, i tried that but can you explain what's happening here: http://www.sallydworsky.com/img/sdtest.jpg - the toggle gets pushed down unless i make both the image and the a fluid which makes it 70% of 70% and the images gets smaller than i want. why is the a box bigger than the image?

Comment: In upper image it shows the width of the img tag which is around 70%. But the pic which is below shows the tag 'a' have 100% width due to which your toggle button comes underneath of the logo.

Comment: You have to use media queries to get your desire output because if you fix your 'a' fluid to 70% then the image will be smaller but it will be gone to 100% then cause a problem with toggle button. but if you media query then when the width of the page is about you mobile size the size of the 'a' will automatically convert into 70%.

Comment: ok, i understand. thanks very much. it's working now how i want it to.

Comment: That's my pleasure to help you. but use max-width: 80%;in your media query. It will be more good. Have a good day